# how to explode into named variable array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

I am getting started with php, and I was wondering if it was possible to explode a string into an array with named variables. The set up is that I have some data I am reading in from a text file, and I want to break it up into rows first and then break it up into individual pieces of data.

```
 Data1  |  Data2  |  Data3  |
 ----------------------------
|   x   |    y    |    z    |
|   p   |    q    |    r    |
```

So I am trying to end up with something like:

```
data {
   row1 {
       data1: x
       data2: y
       data3: z
   row2 {
       data1: p
       data2: q
       data3: r
   }
}
```

and I would like be able to access the data using the names of the variables if possible:

`$r1d1 = data[row1]['data1'];`

Comment: look into associative arrays.

Comment: there is no built in function but you can do it manually. What have you done so far?

Comment: What is the exact structure of your data in the file? You've got some options, such as storing the data in already parsable way, like JSON / XML, or parse it with regular expressions and explodes

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel There is a built in function named extract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to explode a string into an associative array, you can use the list function.

```
// Initialize data_list
$data_list = array();

// Remove delimiter at start and end of string
$string = trim('|   x   |    y    |    z    |', '|');

$data = array();
list($data['data1'],$data['data2'],$data['data3']) = explode('|',$string);

$data_list[] = $data;
```

You would want to have it wrapped into a foreach loop to process each line of the file. In the end the $data_list would contain all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation by code

```
<?php

// data to convert
$string = '| Data1  |  Data2  |  Data3  |
 ----------------------------
|   x   |    y    |    z    |
|   p   |    q    |    r    |';

// container to collect data in
$data = array();

// split the string into lines
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
// pull first line from the array
$names = array_shift($lines);
// remove delimiters from beginning and end
$names = trim($names, '| ');
// split at | while ignoring spaces and empty results
$names = preg_split('/\s*\|\s*/', $names);
// remove --------------- line
array_shift($lines);
// walk remaining lines
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // container to collect data of row in
    $row = array();
    // remove delimiters from beginning and end
    $line = trim($line, '| ');
    // split at |
    $line = explode('|', $line);
    foreach ($line as $i => $value) {
        // identify key by looking up in $names
        $key = $names[$i];
        // remove spaces
        $row[$key] = trim($value);
    }
    // add row to data set
    $data[] = $row;
}

var_dump($data);
```

will result in

```
$data = array(
    0 => array(
        'Data1' => 'x',
        'Data2' => 'y',
        'Data3' => 'z',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Data1' => 'p',
        'Data2' => 'q',
        'Data3' => 'r',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract them [PHP Extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

`extract($your_array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'prefix_if_needed');`

then use

```
    echo '<pre>'; 
      var_export(array_diff(get_defined_vars(), array(array())));  
    echo'</pre>';
```

To see your new variable names ;)

Hope this helps.